# ffmpeg stream to ffserver at lower bitrate (incomming x264 and aac)

Tags: android, ios, ffmpeg, libvlc, avconv

Does anyone have any config files for ffserver and the options to use for  ffmpeg to send lower bitrate to the ffserver and ffserver to stream using hls?

I receive data from a live stream ( a music tv channel) witch is x264 and acc and I want to lower the bitrate cause is to hight.
I want to restream using ffmpeg the original tv channel and decrease the bitrate .
I'll stream to the ffserver so the devices who want to see the channel will not make new internet conenctions will can get the data from local ffserver,so only 1 conection is going to the internet ,the ffmeg one ,the local devices will get data from local ffserver.
But i need to lower the bit rate.

I tried different combinations of ffserver settings and ffmpeg options but i think i do something wrong cause ffmpeg dnt like ffserver settings and when it like them ,bit rate is same.
Please help me if you can.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it sending the streams to woza